# Android: Permissions deny in marshmallow cause crash

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, user-permissions

I have an application that having **contact list** and **camera**, Both permission that I set in **Android Manifest**.The application is working fine in API level 21 and below.

When I install the application in **Marshmallow** API level 23 from the **Play Store**, At the time of installing it didn't ask Permission, When I check in setting all the permission for the app deny.

For this reason when I open the application in **Marshmallow** the application getting crash.

Can anyone please tell me how to give the permission in **Marshmallow** without crash

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: can you add the code of permissions that you use?
I have an application to play store that use camera and it work with marshmallow!
When you download an app from Google Play, when it crash you can get the Log error.
can you post the Log too?

Comment: In settings by default the camera permission is deny for that application. By manualy giving Permission to that from setting , then the app works fine

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to ask for permission in marshmallow, there is no other way to overcome this issue.

to check permission you can use this

```
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
```

If permission is given by user, it will return 0 else will return 1.

if permission is not given, ask user for permission

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
        10);
```

and check whether user have granted permission or not

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "READ_CONTACTS granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "READ_CONTACTS Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

for more information, refer [this](http://androidgig.com/requesting-runtime-permission/)

if you want to give support in pre-marshmallow devices also you need to use

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()
```

rest all things are same as i mentioned above.